# Ryzen 3600 fan speed is very erratic compared to Ryzen 1600x

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen, turbo-boost

I've upgraded to a Ryzen 3600 from a Ryzen 1600x, on the same motherboard (that I had to flash).

One thing I've noticed is that the CPU fan speed will very quickly speed up if I do something mildly "intensive" like open a new program or load a video etc. It'll also very quickly slow down shortly after.

I've manually lowered the fan speeds for lower temperatures (in bios) - and hence the "average" fan speed seems to be much more stable.

Why is the Ryzen 3600 so much more "responsive" to load? Is this something to do with the turbo/boost? Or possibly a bug in the latest bios?

Comment: Are you using the same CPU Cooler as before? Because in later generations, the included Wraith Spire cooler is [**significantly** worse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHhRPTEJ9GY) than the previous one. I got a Ryzen 5 1600 with the excellent previous Wraith Spire, and a Ryzen 5 3400G with the terrible new one that just loud.

Comment: Yup exact same cooler - which is fairly big too - Thermalright Ultra 120.

Answer (score 0):

The base clock speeds of the AMD Ryzen 3600 processor and the AMD Ryzen 1600X  processor are the same. The real difference between the AMD Ryzen 3600 and the AMD Ryzen 1600X is the 7nm manufacturing technology of the AMD Ryzen 3600 vs. 14nm for the AMD Ryzen 1600X. The AMD Ryzen 3600 runs colder than the AMD Ryzen 1600X, especially with a big CPU cooler, which you can see if you install a CPU temperature monitoring app. This makes the AMD Ryzen 3600 more responsive to load.